# HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse hangs periodically when debugger attached to Unity editor

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine

For various reasons I need to use HttpWebRequest instead of the built-in WWW class to call out to web services in our Unity project. I'm finding that Request.EndGetResponse hangs under certain circumstances. The issue is exacerbated when the debugger is attached--it does happen from time to time without the debugger, but happens close to 100% of the time when the debugger is attached. It is only happening when I'm calling a web service using HTTPS.

I plugged in Wireshark to look at the two traces. Oddly, the trace when the debugger is attached includes a "Handshake Failure" where the trace without the debugger does not. The other interesting thing is that the trace that works includes two [FIN, ACK] messages presumably from other failed attempts.

Ultimately I think I'm running into some known issues with the Mono 2.6 threadpool. That said, I don't understand what EndGetResponse is doing that could cause it to hang--I thought this was a synchronous operation. I also don't understand how attaching the debugger could affect the issue.

If there are any mono experts out there, I'd appreciate any insight!

Comment: mono 2.6 is ancient, request Unity3D guys to upgrade their mono version to 3.x

Comment: No kidding, but unfortunately that's what we're stuck with.